# Wired internet connection problem. Ubuntu refuses to connect!

Tags: internet

Hello I'm a new Linux user running a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 and so far haven't been able to connect to the internet. I'm using the network manager included by default. It would appear that it's searching for a wireless connection rather than using my ethernet. I've tried changing settings, like switching the "Method" under the "IPv4 Settings" tab to manual but that didn't work. I tried unplugging my router (Linksys WRT54G) and going in directly through the modem but that didn't work either.

I'm really hoping it's something simple because I'm currently using my router's wireless to post this message while it's plugged into the rig that Ubuntu refuses to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

sorry that you are getting this problem.
First, go to the dash and type "additional drives" and see if there are any drivers available or even in use for networking.

Also, if that does not help post the make/model of your computer and ill see if I can find the wired/wireless drivers.